# How to add column with values in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am new to Swing. I have `JTable` with columns. I want to add a new column to the existing table with values in it. I am able to add a new column in table using `model.addColumn("test")`. But it gives me blank column - rather I want to display values in column and add it in the table.

Comment: Just fill the column's values using TableModel's method public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex);

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DefaultTableModel#addColumn(Object, Object[]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addColumn(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object[]))

> Adds a column to the model. The new column will have the identifier
>   columnName. columnData is the optional array of data for the column.
>   If it is null the column is filled with null values. Otherwise, the
>   new data will be added to model starting with the first element going
>   to row 0, etc. This method will send a tableChanged notification
>   message to all the listeners.

Answer (score 0):

//I make new model

```
    private void setNewTableModel(){

        String[] header = new String[nArrays + 1];
        header[0] = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < header.length; i++)
            header[i] = "Array" + i;
        Object[][] data = new Object[4][nArrays + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
            for (int j = 1; j < header.length; j++){
            data[i][0] = "\"" + (i + 2) + "\"";
            data[i][j]=j+i;
        }
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, header));
    }
```